# Why isn't this centering the div in the middle of body?

Tags: html, css, center

```
<style>
  .maincont {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    background: purple;
  }

  body {
    background: limegreen;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="maincont"></div>
</body>
```

Why doesn't this code make the purple square centered in the page? The `flex-direction` property set to column should have placed it in the middle vertically right?

Comment: It _is_ centered in the the middle of body. Give body a border and you will see.

Answer (score -1):

After I checked there is no problem with it, the purple box can be in center of the page, try clearing cache and cookies on the browser you are using then restart